# Trying to pass local variables to other modules in Python

Tags: python, function, variables

I am a beginner to Python and i'm having a hell of a time trying to get this program to work. I need to pass local variables to other modules and I've tried multiple things and I can't get it to work. It's just a Extremely simple program that calculates commission. I've literally spent hours trying to get it to work. I'm using the latest version of Python.

```
import os

def main():
    input_salesperson_data()
    commission = calculate_commission(sales_amount)
    determine_bonus(years_worked, commission)
    output_commission(name, commission)


def input_salesperson_data():
    name = (input("\n\t\tWhat is the full name of the salesperson: "))
    sales_amount = float(input("\n\t\tWhat is the sales amount of the salesperson: "))
    years_worked = int (input("\n\t\tHow many years has the salesperson worked for the company: "))
    return(name, sales_amount, years_worked)

def calculate_commission(sales_amount):
    commission_rate1 = 0.15
    commission_rate2 = 0.25
    commission_rate3 = 0.30

    if sales_amount <= 20000:
         commission = sales_amount * commission_rate1

    elif sales_amount > 20000 and sales_amount <= 40000:
         commission = sales_amount * commission_rate2

    else:
         commission = sales_amount * commission_rate3
    return(commission)

def determine_bonus(sales_amount, years_worked, commission):

    if years_worked > 20:
        commission *= 2
    return(commission)  

def output_commission(name, commission):
    os.system("cls")
    print("\n\n\t\t\t SALESPERSON COMMISSION REPORT")
    print("\n\t\t\tSalesperson Name: ",   name)
    print("\t\t\tCommission Amount: ",   format(commission, ',.2f'))
    input("\n\t\tPress enter to exit...")
    os._exit(1)

main()
```

Comment: You declared that `determine_bonus` takes 3 arguments, but you pass it 2 and don't do anything with the return value. What's up with that?

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what the `return` statement does. From the looks of your code, you seem to expect it to take a number of variables and copy them into the caller's namespace. That's not what it does. It halts the current function and causes the function call to evaluate to the specified value. For example, if I declare a function `def four(): return 4`, then `3 + four() == 7`.

Comment: Also, don't use `os._exit`. Python will exit when it finishes executing your file's code; you don't need to explicitly tell it to exit. Even if you did, `os._exit` is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @user2357112: good advice, plus (1) is the code for failure, where here it is used after success!

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the tips, looks I'll have to do some more research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    information = input_salesperson_data()
    commission = calculate_commission(information[1]) 
    determine_bonus(information[2], commission)
    output_commission(information[0], commission)
```

In python, the scope of the variable is contained in the function; however, in `input_salesperson_data()`, you're returning a tuple, but not saving it.  `information` will save what is returned by `input_salesperson_data()`, and you can access what you need as shown above.

Also, in `calculate_commission()`, you can simple return `commission`.  Additionally, you don't need to manually exit the program.

Finally, change:

```
def determine_bonus(sales_amount, years_worked, commission):
```

to

```
def determine_bonus(years_worked, commission):
```

as `sales_amount` is completely irrelevant.

Comment: line 14, in <module> main() Type:Error: determine_bonus() missing 1 required positional argument: 'commission'

Comment: @user3027217 That's because I followed your example, which only passed two arguments, but you asked for three in your method header. Fixed.  PS: you really should look at your code.  Just because you see an error message that you don't understand doesn't mean that you can't figure it out.

Comment: Wow, that completely flew over my head. Thanks a TON for the help. I think my frustration was getting the better of me, sorry.